# XSD Schema for XML Element which has a value and an Attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

How could be XSD for this element?

```
<Message isEnabled="true">Message body</Message>
```

I have searched in Google but there are only examples where **Message** is a complex type, not element with type.

Or this is wrong format for XML at all?

Comment: DanM shows you an example. Unfortunately this is a case where Google will only work if you know the answer, namely that what you have here is known as a "complex type with simple content". This is why I prefer to learn a language from a good book, rather than from searching the web - if you are using XSD, then having an XSD textbook on your desk is almost indispensible.

Comment: You're right, but I'm limited in time, and my touch with XML and XSD is too little to spend time for learning from the book. Thanks anyway, I agree that searching everything in Google and copying examples to our solutions is a bad practice :))

Comment: Well, you're smarter than I am then. If I tried to write schemas without a book by my side I would have wasted months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="Message">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="isEnabled" type="xs:boolean" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```